# Load datajs-1.1.2.min.js into SAP UI5 Application

Tags: javascript, sapui5, datajs

I need to load the JS library datajs-1.1.2.min into my SAP UI5 Application but the UI5 framework automatically load own datajs.js under the path ui/thirdparty, that is an older version .

I put the datajs-1.1.2.min into my application's folder and imported into the index.html page so the library is loaded but I can't use it. The application continue to call the older library.

Is there a way to force the application to use the new library?
Thanks

Comment: import required datajs-1.1.2.min,js after SAPUI5 bootstrap script or inside the body of index.html

Comment: Show us your bootstrap